# JdbcTemplate 'IN' search not working properly

Tags: mysql, spring-mvc, jdbctemplate

I am trying to perform IN search using JbdcTemplate in Spring. Here goes my code

```
@Override
    public Map<String, List> dataRetriveForAsset(String type) {

List<Integer> interfaceIdList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
List<Integer> fileList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

String sql2 = "select interface_id from tbl_interface_asset where asset_id in ( :ids )";

//fileList is populated with a different query

Set<Integer> ids = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(new Integer[fileList.size()] ));

        for(int i=0; i<fileList.size();i++)
        {
            ids.add(fileList.get(i));
        }       
        MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        parameters.addValue("ids", ids);

interfaceIdList = jdbcTemplate.query(sql2,new ListMapper1(),parameters );
```

and the sql2 query part executes it throws the following error.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [appServlet] in context with path [/iccdashboard] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [select interface_id from tbl_interface_asset where asset_id in ( :ids )]; Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException] with root cause
java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setSerializableObject(PreparedStatement.java:4401)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setObject(PreparedStatement.java:4083)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:351)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:216)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:144)
```

But if I use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, I am getting a BadSQLGrammarError because the 'ids' value my sql query goes emplty like below.

```
select interface_id from tbl_interface_asset where asset_id in ( )
```

Comment: `JdbcTemplate` knows nothing of a `SqlParameterSource`. The `NamedJdbcTemplate` on the other hand does... Change the one you use to the proper one. Another thing create the template once and not each time you need one, it is thread safe and will give you a performance boost as constructing a template is quite a heavy operation.

Comment: But when I use NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, I am getting BadSQLGrammarError. Please see the updated post. just now updated.

Comment: Why not execute a single query instead of 2? Put your query selecting the ids into the in clause (should be faster then this approach). Yuor list/set is probably empty. Without seeing the actual code that is impossible to say for sure. You shouldn't need the set simply pass the list to the `MapSqlParameterSource`

Comment: Great Idea Deinum. The query is working now, but still it is not giving the complete result. I have posted the problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488498/mysql-in-clause-problems. Please refer to it and help me.

Comment: Sorry Denium, Its my fault. I executed a wrong query in jdbcTemplate. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Remember to accept an answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> java.io.NotSerializableException: org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.MapSqlParameterSource

I was able to fix this problem by replacing my usage of

```
org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate
```

with the:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate
```

I was using the `MapSqlParameterSource` class but using the standard template which may have been the problem.

> But if I use `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`, I am getting a BadSQLGrammarError because the 'ids' value my sql query goes empty like below.

Can you make the SQL generation conditional on whether or not there are entries in your `IN` collection?

```
if (!ids.isEmpty()) {
    parameters.addValue("ids", ids);
}
```

Comment: on point. It should be an acceptable answer. Thank you.