# mysql 'IN' clause problems

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having two tables like below,

```
Table Apple:

----------------------------------------
      id         |       type          |
----------------------------------------
   1             |         3           |
----------------------------------------
   2             |         3           |
----------------------------------------
   3             |          3          |
----------------------------------------


Table Orange:

-------------------------------------------
      orange id     |      apple id       |
-------------------------------------------
         1          |            1         |
-------------------------------------------
         2          |             2        |
-------------------------------------------
         3          |             3        |
-------------------------------------------
         4          |             1        |
-------------------------------------------- 
         4          |             2        |
--------------------------------------------
         4          |             3        |
--------------------------------------------
```

and my query goes like below,

```
SELECT orange_id 
FROM   orange 
WHERE  apple_id IN (SELECT id 
                    FROM   apple 
                    WHERE  type = 3);
```

The above query is returning the following result set,

1, 2, 3

But I need 1,2,3,4. Where my query is going wrong.? Please help me.

Comment: That is not a great way to be doing that query if the tables get much bigger.

Comment: Are you sure about the result?  Should def be returning 6 rows...

Comment: With this data your query should return 1,2,3,4,4,4

Comment: Works for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d48f6/1

Comment: Yes of course David. It should return 6 rows.

Comment: try using `select distinct orange_id from Orange where apple_id in ( select id from Apple where type= 3 );` to get 1,2,3,4

Comment: If you really are getting only 1,2,3 as results, then there is something you aren't telling us.

Comment: @Barmar query working fine

Comment: Sorry folks, Tim is right, There is nothing wrong in the query. Just now tried in mysql workbench. It is working fine. But the same query is not working in Spring JdbcTemplate. I am sure nothing is wrong with jdbcTemplate query.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use a join instead? That query looks ugly and not optimized, yet, I still don't know why it's not working. Use a join similar to this one...

```
select orange_id from Orange
inner join Apple on Apple.id = Orange.apple_id
where Apple.type = 3
```

Hope it helps
Leo

Comment: I am very sorry guys. Sorry for wasting your time. Its my careless mistake. But I got an optimized code from Leo. Thank you Leo.